# How to generate a class diagram from Android project using Papyrus?

Tags: android, eclipse, papyrus

I installed papyrus on eclipse in order to generate the class diagram of a Android application I worked on but I can't find how to generate that. I searched on the net, I only found how to create a new project from scratch and not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think Papyrus alone would do reverse engineering of Java Code: it is more oriented around Java code generation from UML model.
You have [some plugins for reverse](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/149226/), not necessarely maintained though.

However, from [this post](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1015475/), using payrus *in addition* of **[Modisco](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?nav=/38)** could be closer of what you are looking for. See [Modisco wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/MoDisco), and this [step-by-step thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/841461/).

---

The [OP user2137817](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2137817/user2137817) [offers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550889/how-to-generate-a-class-diagram-from-android-project-using-papyrus/15565488?noredirect=1#comment22078524_15565488) another alternative: [**objectaid**](http://www.objectaid.com/):

> The ObjectAid UML Explorer is an agile and lightweight code visualization tool for the Eclipse IDE. It shows your Java source code and libraries in live UML class and sequence diagrams that automatically update as your code changes.
>   The image below is a class diagram of actual source code:

[image: objectaid]